# Demonstration of the nullity of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been requested to demonstrate, through the application of properties (no calculus), that the determinant of the following matrix is zero:

\begin{bmatrix}{x}&{y}&{2x+3y}\\{4}&{3}&{17}\\{z}&{t}&{2z+3t}\end{bmatrix}

If I triangulate the matrix operating with linear combinations of rows, I get one row of zeros, situation that takes me to the null result I want to prove, but through calculations.

I wonder how can I demonstrate it, avoiding what I described.

Comment: Notice that $C_3= 2C_1+3C_2$, where $C_i$'s are columns.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I should have observed more strongly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asked to use properties of the determinant maybe you can argue that because $det(A)=det(A^t)$ then you can observe what Sahiba told you before and, hence, conclude that $det(A)=0$

Comment: Is precisely what I ended doing. Anyway, thanks for the observation!